# Large log aggregation and count, what tools should I choose?

Tags: logging, count, aggregation, apache-kafka

Input: Apache Kafka with Ngnix log(milliseconds level) from multiple servers, the logs is generally ordered by time, but not exactly.

Proceed: What tools or tech. should I choose ???

Output: Text with format:  URL    time(minute level)    count

e.g.

Input: 2015-06-24 12:23:34.001 /rest/login?user=xxx HTTP/1.0 ...

Output: /rest/login "2015-06-24 12:23" 2

Thanks very much for your reply

BTW. parsing the log is not the problem, but how to do the aggregation and count.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: e.g. Input: 2015-06-24 12:23:34.001 /rest/login?user=xxx HTTP/1.0 ...

Comment: e.g. Output:  /rest/login    "2015-06-24 12:23"   2

Comment: For now, I use python to parse the log and save the result to redis with command hincrby. And export the result to text every 10minutes.